# No provider for _HttpClient

Tags: angular, http

I'm working on a personal project with Angular 17, and there are some settings that I get from the backend of my application. But my Angular `HttpClient` does not work and honestly I don't know why not.

The error that I get is this:

> ERROR Error [NullInjectorError]: R3InjectorError(Standalone[_AppComponent])[_GetSettingsService -> _GetSettingsService -> _HttpClient -> _HttpClient]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for _HttpClient!
> at NullInjector.get (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:5465:13)
> at R3Injector.get (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:5916:22)
> at R3Injector.get (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:5916:22)
> at injectInjectorOnly (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:912:12)
> at Module.ɵɵinject (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:998:53)
> at Object.GetSettingsService_Factory (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\src\app\shared\services\get-settings.service.ts:9:32)
> at eval (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:6028:10)
> at runInInjectorProfilerContext (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:873:5)
> at R3Injector.hydrate (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:6027:11)
> at R3Injector.get (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:5907:7) {
> ngTempTokenPath: null,
> ngTokenPath: [
> '_GetSettingsService',
> '_GetSettingsService',
> '_HttpClient',
> '_HttpClient'
> ]
> }
> Error [NullInjectorError]: R3InjectorError(Standalone[_AppComponent])[_GetSettingsService -> _GetSettingsService -> _HttpClient -> _HttpClient]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for _HttpClient!
> at NullInjector.get (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:5465:13)
> at R3Injector.get (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:5916:22)
> at R3Injector.get (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:5916:22)
> at injectInjectorOnly (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:912:12)
> at Module.ɵɵinject (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:998:53)
> at Object.GetSettingsService_Factory (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\src\app\shared\services\get-settings.service.ts:9:32)
> at eval (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:6028:10)
> at runInInjectorProfilerContext (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:873:5)
> at R3Injector.hydrate (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:6027:11)
> at R3Injector.get (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:5907:7) {
> ngTempTokenPath: null,
> ngTokenPath: [
> '_GetSettingsService',
> '_GetSettingsService',
> '_HttpClient',
> '_HttpClient'
> ]
> }
> 14:23:23 [vite] Internal server error: R3InjectorError(Standalone[_AppComponent])[_GetSettingsService -> _GetSettingsService -> _HttpClient -> _HttpClient]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for _HttpClient!
> at NullInjector.get (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules@angular\core\fesm2022\co14:23:23 [vite] Internal server error: R3InjectorError(Standalone[_AppComponent])[_GetSettingsService -> _GetSettingsService -> _HttpClient -> _HttpClient]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for _HttpClient!
> at NullInjector.get (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:5465:13)
> at R3Injector.get (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:5916:22)
> at R3Injector.get (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:5916:22)
> at injectInjectorOnly (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:912:12)
> at Module.ɵɵinject (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:998:53)
> at Object.GetSettingsService_Factory (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\src\app\shared\services\get-settings.service.ts:9:32)
> at eval (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:6028:10)
> at runInInjectorProfilerContext (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:873:5)
> at R3Injector.hydrate (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:6027:11)
> at R3Injector.get (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:5907:7) (x2)

My app.component.ts :

```
import { GetSettingsService } from './shared/services/get-settings.service';
import { NavheaderComponent } from './components/navheader/navheader.component';
import { Component, NgModule, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { ConfigComponent } from './components/config/config.component';
import { TerminalComponent } from './components/terminal/terminal.component';
import { StaticEffectComponent } from './components/static-effect/static-effect.component';
import { UserConfig } from './shared/models/userConfigs.model';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterOutlet,
    NavheaderComponent,
    ConfigComponent,
    TerminalComponent,
    StaticEffectComponent,
  ],
  providers: [
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'pip-boy-3000';

  constructor(private getSettingsService: GetSettingsService) {}


  //Ambient Variables
  public userConfig: UserConfig = new UserConfig();


  //Used for activating the Config Panel;
  public configIsActivated: boolean = false;
  public noisyBackground: boolean = true;

  public setNoisyBackground(e: boolean) {
    this.noisyBackground = e;
  }

  public activateOrDeactivateConfig(e: any): void {
    console.log(e);
    this.configIsActivated = e;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getSettingsService.getSettingsInfos(1).subscribe({
      error: () => {
        console.log("error")
      },
      next: (data: UserConfig) => {
        this.userConfig = data;
      }
    })
  }
}
```

My service

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { UserConfig } from '../models/userConfigs.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class GetSettingsService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  public getSettingsInfos(userId: number): Observable<UserConfig> {
    return this.httpClient.get<UserConfig>(`/settings/${userId}`);
  }
}
```

i tried multiple times changing some things, creating modules and other sort of things, and i dont know what can i do

**EDIT**

Ive also changed the location of the HttpClientModule from providers to imports, but then this error comes in:

```
ERROR Error [NullInjectorError]: R3InjectorError(Standalone[_AppComponent])[_GetSettingsService -> _GetSettingsService -> _HttpClient -> _HttpClient]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for _HttpClient!
    at NullInjector.get (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000\.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules\@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:5465:13)
    at R3Injector.get (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000\.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules\@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:5916:22)
    at R3Injector.get (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000\.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules\@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:5916:22)
    at injectInjectorOnly (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000\.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules\@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:912:12)
    at Module.ɵɵinject (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000\.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules\@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:998:53)
    at Object.GetSettingsService_Factory (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000\.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\src\app\shared\services\get-settings.service.ts:9:32)
    at eval (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000\.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules\@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:6028:10)
    at runInInjectorProfilerContext (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000\.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules\@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:873:5)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000\.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules\@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:6027:11)
    at R3Injector.get (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000\.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules\@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:5907:7) {
  ngTempTokenPath: null,
  ngTokenPath: [
    '_GetSettingsService',
    '_GetSettingsService',
    '_HttpClient',
    '_HttpClient'
  ]
}
Error [NullInjectorError]: R3InjectorError(Standalone[_AppComponent])[_GetSettingsService -> _GetSettingsService -> _HttpClient -> _HttpClient]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for _HttpClient!
    at NullInjector.get (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000\.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules\@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:5465:13)
    at R3Injector.get (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000\.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules\@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:5916:22)
    at R3Injector.get (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000\.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules\@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:5916:22)
    at injectInjectorOnly (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000\.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules\@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:912:12)
    at Module.ɵɵinject (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000\.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules\@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:998:53)
    at Object.GetSettingsService_Factory (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000\.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\src\app\shared\services\get-settings.service.ts:9:32)
    at eval (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000\.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules\@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:6028:10)
    at runInInjectorProfilerContext (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000\.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules\@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:873:5)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000\.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules\@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:6027:11)
    at R3Injector.get (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000\.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules\@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:5907:7) {
  ngTempTokenPath: null,
  ngTokenPath: [
    '_GetSettingsService',
    '_GetSettingsService',
    '_HttpClient',
    '_HttpClient'
  ]
}
16:37:53 [vite] Internal server error: R3InjectorError(Standalone[_AppComponent])[_GetSettingsService -> _GetSettingsService -> _HttpClient -> _HttpClient]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for _HttpClient!
      at NullInjector.get (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000\.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules\@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:5465:13)
      at R3Injector.get (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000\.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules\@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:5916:22)
      at R3Injector.get (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000\.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules\@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:5916:22)
      at injectInjectorOnly (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000\.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules\@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:912:12)
      at Module.ɵɵinject (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000\.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules\@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:998:53)
      at Object.GetSettingsService_Factory (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000\.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\src\app\shared\services\get-settings.service.ts:9:32)
      at eval (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000\.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules\@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:6028:s:6028:10)
      at runInInjectorProfilerContext (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000\.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules\@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:873:5)
      at R3Injector.hydrate (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000\.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules\@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:6027:11)
      at R3Injector.get (C:\Users\user\Documents\Works\pip-boy-3000\.angular\vite-root\pip-boy-3000\node_modules\@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:5907:7)
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I was dealing with the same issue until I had a close look at the new documentation [here at angular.dev](https://angular.dev/guide/http/setup#providing-httpclient-through-dependency-injection), which tells you how to provide `HttpClient` to a standalone app:

> `HttpClient` is provided using the `provideHttpClient` helper function, which most apps include in the application `providers` in `main.ts`.
>
> ```
> boostrapApplication(App, {providers: [
>   provideHttpClient(),
> ]});
> ```

Lastly, since it's a standalone app you're dealing with, importing `HttpClientModule` doesn't do anything that would've made Angular provide `HttpClient` to your app to begin with, so feel free to remove the `HttpClientModule` import from `app.component.ts` afterwards.

Comment: Many thanks, you saved me! That should be considered the right answer, since the OP is about the new Angular 17.

Answer (score 12):

For me the solution was put the line 'provideHttpClient()' in a file named 'app.config.ts'. I'm using Angular 17.0.5

Comment: Yeah, in that case your `app.config.ts` is exporting an object which may for example be named `appConfig`, and your `main.ts` would be importing and using it like that: `bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig);`

Answer (score 6):

In angular 17 you have to provide this httpClient using **provideHttpClient()** method.
This method need to pass in provides in app.config.ts

```
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideRouter(routes), **provideHttpClient()**]
};
```

Now it will work.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the HttpClientModule, not provide it. So remove it from the provides array and add it to the imports array.

Comment: I tried doing this, but it also continues that error

R3InjectorError(Standalone[_AppComponent])[_GetSettingsService -> _GetSettingsService -> _HttpClient -> _HttpClient]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for _HttpClient!

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 16 i came across same error and I find the solution which work for me.

In Angular 16 even though importing HttpClientModule it can't resolve the error.

In app.config.ts we need to import **provideHttpClient()** in provider Array.

```
export const appConfig: 
ApplicationConfig = { 
providers:[provideRouter(routes),provideHttpClient()] 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular 17

app.config.ts:

import { provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
providers: [
...
provideHttpClient(),
],
};

Answer (score 0):

Go to your app.config.ts file and add the follow:

```
  provideHttpClient()
```

the code should looks like the following:

```
 import { ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
 import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

 import { routes } from './app.routes';
 import { provideClientHydration } from '@angular/platform-browser';
 import { provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

 export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
   providers: [provideRouter(routes), 
 provideClientHydration(),provideHttpClient()]
 };
```

It worked for me in Angular-17

Answer (score 0):

```js
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideRouter(routes),    
    provideHttpClient(),
    {provide:SomeOtherService}    ],  
};
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are . Please [edit✏️] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.